# Java double casting (int[]) (int[])

Tags: java, casting

What does `(int[]) (int[])` do ?

```
private Object[] slots = new Object[8192];

int[] block = (int[]) (int[]) this.slots[0];
```

Comment: Nothing that `(int[])` doesn't do.

Comment: you have a redundant casting.

Comment: You cast this.slots[0] to int[], then you do it again.

Comment: Why don't you give us any indication why would you expect it to do something.

Comment: This question would be funnier if the data type was Double instead of int.

Comment: this code came out of JD-core decompiler..

Comment: The decompiler gets confused in a lot of situations. This is an example. There is no deeper meaning to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, the second cast does nothing. It is the same as typing

```
private Object[] slots = new Object[8192];

int[] block = (int[]) this.slots[0];
block = (int[]) block;
```

EDIT:

To clarify, the "second" cast that I am referring to is the one on the left.

Comment: Isn't it the *first* cast which does nothing?

Comment: @bzlm good point, however I read Bort's answer as he meant it (I hope), the second cast is the one on the left :-)